# Can't reach web application hosted on Azure Linux server

Tags: ubuntu, azure, web-server

I have successfully deployed an [Open Semantic Search](https://www.opensemanticsearch.org/) web application on a Ubuntu server hosted on Azure. While the server is running (using eLinks from the shell, I can connect to `http://localhost/search`), I'm unable to connect to it from outside using `http://<ip_address>/search`.

Any idea of what I might have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that any Azure Network Security Group that is applied to the VM or the subnet the VM is in, allows inbound traffic on the required port for your application.

Comment: Yes, you pointed to the right direction and I found the detailed instructions [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal). Thanks!